# Problem with the abstract in a IEEE conference document class

Tags: ieeetran, abstract

I am using the conference `IEEEtran` document class, and when I type the abstract, instead of being centered, it is on the left column. The instructions say to use the command `\IEEEtitleabstractindextext` and to use it like a section, but when I do so, the abstract simply disappears.

What do I do?

Would you give me an example on how to use the command?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code for a small document we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The `IEEEtran` documentclass follows the IEEE style definitions *very, very, very* closely... Luckily, everything is well documented in the `IEEEtran-HOWTO.pdf` document, which is supplied together with the style definitions and a couple of example documents. Please *read* this document! It contains rules on how to create IEEE-conform papers and many helpful hints.

As described in section V (abstract and index terms),

> The IEEE Computer Society and IEEE Transactions on Magnetics formats present a difficulty in that `compsoc` and `transmag` journal (**but not `compsoc conference`**) papers place the abstract and index terms sections in *single column format just below the author names, but the other IEEE formats place them in the first column of the main text before the first section.

That is why the `\IEEEtitleabstractindextext` command is only enabled in `compsoc` and `transmag` mode, but not in `compsoc`+`conference` mode.

The documentation is also very specific in how the command is used: The following code has to be placed *before* the `\maketitle` command. Further, they propose to use the command `\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext` directly *after* `\maketitle` - this combination always typesets the abstract as required by the current settings: in one-column mode for `compsoc` and `transmag`, and in two-column mode for most others.

```
% abstract and (if needed) index terms
\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{%
    \begin{abstract}
        We propose \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
}

% make the title area
\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
```

At the bottom of this answer, I included an example document to show the effect of the documentclass settings on the output, when you use the commands as recommended above.

The first image shows the output for `compsoc` mode, and *not* `conference` mode: the abstract is set in one-column mode. The second image shows the output for both `conference` and `compsoc` mode enabled: the abstract is in two-column mode.

[image: compsoc and NOT conference]

[image: compsoc and conference]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Demo of single-column abstracts}
\author{Homer J. Simpson}

\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
We propose \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Broad band networks, quality of service, WDM.
\end{IEEEkeywords}}

% make the title area
\maketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-7]

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```