# IEEE template: help with index words

Tags: indexing, templates, ieeetran

Relatively new to LaTeX and trying to use IEEE trans template for journals but I have run into a problem.

I do not want to use index terms but I can't seem to get rid of it without causing an error. I believe it is due to `\IEEEtitleabstractindextext` line but don't know an alternative so please help.

The main code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}}

\maketitle

\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
```

Comment: Welcome on Tex.SE, could you please post a full [MWE](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) to see what the issue is?

Comment: possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338854/problem-with-the-abstract-in-a-ieee-conference-document-class

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to use `\IEEEtitleabstractindextext` in a mode which does not allow you to do so. My suggestion is that you either change the document mode or do not use the command.

Also, you might want to look at this question: [Problem with the abstract in a IEEE conference document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338854/problem-with-the-abstract-in-a-ieee-conference-document-class)